# changing background color with :checked in css

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of the box once i check the checkbox, but it doesn't work with the code i wrote. am i missing something? thanks

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked .box{
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" />
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this rule doesn't work because `.box` is not in `input`

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked .box
```

but you can use [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .box
```

or [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator):

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .box
```